# TableView column does not display Integer values. (Java FX)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a Java desctop app to show information about tram stop (like shcedule). The programm read information from xml file and write it in table. I use Scene Builder to build GUI with TableView, but column "Passangers" does not display me Integer values. What could be the problem?

[image]

Here is my controller:

```
public class HoursController implements Initializable {

    private XMLStation station = new XMLStation();

    private ObservableList<AbstractHour> observableList;

    public static void showMessage(String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("");
        alert.setHeaderText(message);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void showError(String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText(message);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public static FileChooser getFileChooser(String title) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("."));

        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML-files (*.xml)", "*.xml"));
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All files (*.*)", "*.*"));

        fileChooser.setTitle(title);
        return fileChooser;
    }

    @FXML TextField textFieldStation;
    @FXML TextField textFieldText;
    @FXML TextArea textAreaResults;
    @FXML TableView<AbstractHour> tableViewHours;
    @FXML TableColumn<AbstractHour, String> tableColumnTime;
    @FXML TableColumn<AbstractHour, Integer> tableColumnPassAmount;
    @FXML TableColumn<AbstractHour, String> tableColumnComment;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        tableViewHours.setPlaceholder(new Label(""));
    }

    @FXML
    public void doNew(ActionEvent event) {
        station = new XMLStation();
        observableList = null;
        textFieldStation.setText("");
        textFieldText.setText("");
        textAreaResults.setText("");
        tableViewHours.setItems(null);
        tableViewHours.setPlaceholder(new Label(""));
    }

    @FXML
    public void doOpen(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = getFileChooser("Open XML-file");
        File file;
        if ((file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)) != null) {
            try {
                station.readFromFile(file.getCanonicalPath());

                textFieldStation.setText(station.getName());
                textAreaResults.setText("");

                tableViewHours.setItems(null);
                updateTable();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                showError("File not found");
            }
            catch (JAXBException e) {
                showError("Wrong file format");
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void doSave(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = getFileChooser("Save XML-file");
        File file;
        if ((file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null)) != null) {
            try {
                updateSourceData(); 
                station.writeToFile(file.getCanonicalPath());
                showMessage("Results were succesfuly saved");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                showError("Can't write to file");
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void doExit(ActionEvent event) {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @FXML 
    public void doAdd(ActionEvent event) {
        station.addHour("---", 0, "----");
        updateTable(); 
    }

    @FXML 
    public void doRemove(ActionEvent event) {

        if (observableList == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (observableList.size() > 0) {
            observableList.remove(observableList.size() - 1);
        }

        if (observableList.size() <= 0) {
            observableList = null;
        }
    }

    @FXML public void doSortByPassangers(ActionEvent event) {
        updateSourceData();
        station.sortByPassangers();
        updateTable();
    }

    @FXML public void doSortByComments(ActionEvent event) {
        updateSourceData();
        station.sortByComments();
        updateTable();
    }

    @FXML public void doAbout(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("About programm...");
        alert.setHeaderText("Tram station (Best programm in the word\n from the best programmer in the word)");
        alert.setContentText("Ver. 1.0");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML public void nameChanged(ActionEvent event) {

        station.setName(textFieldStation.getText());
    }

    @FXML public void doSearchByWord(ActionEvent event) {

        updateSourceData();
        textAreaResults.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < station.hoursCount(); i++) {
            AbstractHour h = station.getHour(i);
            if (h.containsWord(textFieldText.getText())) {
                showResults(h);
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML public void doSearchBySubstring(ActionEvent event) {

        updateSourceData();
        textAreaResults.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < station.hoursCount(); i++) {
            AbstractHour h = station.getHour(i);
            if (h.containsSubstring(textFieldText.getText())) {
                showResults(h);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showResults(AbstractHour hour) {
        textAreaResults.appendText("Time: " + hour.getTime() + " року.\n");
        textAreaResults.appendText("Passangers:" + hour.getPassAmount() + "\n");
        textAreaResults.appendText("Comment:" + hour.getComment() + "\n");
        textAreaResults.appendText("\n");
    }

    private void updateSourceData() {
        station.clearHours();
        for (AbstractHour c : observableList) {
            station.addHour(c);
        }
    }

    private void updateTime(CellEditEvent<AbstractHour, String> t) {
        TablePosition<AbstractHour, String> pos = t.getTablePosition();
        String newTime = t.getNewValue();

        int row = pos.getRow();
        AbstractHour h = t.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
        h.setTime(newTime);
    }

    private void updatePass(CellEditEvent<AbstractHour, Integer> t) {

        System.out.println(t.getNewValue());
        AbstractHour h = t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());
        int newValue = t.getNewValue();
        h.setPassAmount(newValue);
    }

    private void updateComment(CellEditEvent<AbstractHour, String> t) {

        AbstractHour h = t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());
        h.setComment(t.getNewValue());
    }

    private void updateTable() {
        List<AbstractHour> list = new ArrayList<AbstractHour>();
        observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);

        for (int i = 0; i < station.hoursCount(); i++) {
            list.add(station.getHour(i));
        }
        tableViewHours.setItems(observableList);
        //tableViewHours.setItems(observableList);

        tableColumnTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("time"));
        tableColumnTime.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColumnTime.setOnEditCommit(t -> updateTime(t));

        tableColumnPassAmount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("passamount"));
        tableColumnPassAmount.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
        tableColumnPassAmount.setOnEditCommit(t -> updatePass(t));

        tableColumnComment.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("comment"));
        tableColumnComment.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColumnComment.setOnEditCommit(t -> updateComment(t));


    }
}
```

Here is my fxml class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="619.0" prefWidth="989.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="bilous.laba3.oneGUI.HoursController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="801.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doNew" text="New" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doOpen" text="Open" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSave" text="Save" />
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doExit" text="Exit" />
               </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doAdd" text="Add Row" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doRemove" text="Delete last row" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Actions">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSortByPassangers" text="Sort by passangers" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSortByComments" text="Sort by comments" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doAbout" text="About" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <left>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="587.0" prefWidth="233.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Station:" />
            <TextField fx:id="textFieldStation" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="41.0" onAction="#nameChanged" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="198.0" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="122.0" text="Text for searching" />
            <TextField fx:id="textFieldText" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="149.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <Button layoutX="11.0" layoutY="192.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSearchByWord" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="201.0" text="Search by word" />
            <Button layoutX="11.0" layoutY="234.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSearchBySubstring" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="201.0" text="Search by substring" />
            <TextArea fx:id="textAreaResults" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="282.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="&#10;&#10;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="105.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="282.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <center>
      <TableView fx:id="tableViewHours" editable="true" prefHeight="587.0" prefWidth="749.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="tableColumnTime" editable="true" prefWidth="222.0" text="Time" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tableColumnPassAmount" editable="true" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="Passangers" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tableColumnComment" editable="true" prefWidth="361.0" text="Comment" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: `new PropertyValueFactory<>("passamount")` is there a `getPassamount`  which returns integer in `AbstractHour` ?

Comment: You need to use `new PropertyValueFactory<>("passAmount")` (at least there's a `getPassAmount` method used in `showResults` indicating that `amount` should be uppercase in the property name you pass to `PropertyValueFactory`).

Comment: good to show your code - better to not show the "real" stuff but a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (emphasis on _m_ while still being verifiable :)

Comment: also note: if you have control about the data class it's a good idea to expose its properties as fx properties (vs. only getters/setters). Advantages: a) usually no need for custom edit handlers b) you can return the properties in cellValueFactory, thus sparing you the error-prone string config of a PropertyVF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution:

```
tableColumnTest.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("passAmount"));
```

`passAmount` is required (integer) value from AbstractHour.